# sequelize where date clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

- OS: Linux (Lubuntu)
- language: Javascript (Node js)
- framework: express js
- Database: mysql
- "data" is a Date field from "activitat" table

When I run the next statement using Sequelize.js

```
models.TblActivitat.findAll(
                {
                    attributes: 
                    [
                        'codiAct', 'procedencia', 'pacient', 'proces', 'prova', 'rmn', 'realitzador',
                        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('data'), '%d-%m-%Y'), 'data']
                    ],
                    include: models.TblTecnics,
                    where: {"data": '2016-10-20' },   //dataAAAAMMDD
                    order: "registre DESC"
                }).then(function(tblActTec){
                    ...
                });
```

... I'd have to get some records, but I get nothing

running on mysql I get the results:
    mysql> select data from activitat where data = **'2016-10-20'**;
    +------------+
    | data       |
    +------------+
    | 2016-10-20 |
    | 2016-10-20 |
    | 2016-10-20 |
    | 2016-10-20 |
    +------------+

If I see the console of the Node server. When the satement before is executed, it shows as follow:

Executing (default): SELECT `activitat`.`codiAct`  `activitat`.`procedencia`,   `activitat`.`pacient`,  `activitat`.`proces`, `activitat`.`prova`, `activitat`.`rmn`, `activitat`.`realitzador`, date_format(`data`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `data`, `tecnic`.`codiTec` AS `tecnic.codiTec`, `tecnic`.`nom` AS `tecnic.nom` FROM `activitat` AS `activitat` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tecnics` AS `tecnic` ON `activitat`.`realitzador` = `tecnic`.`codiTec`   WHERE `activitat`.`data` = '***2016-10-19 22:00:00***'
ORDER BY registre DESC;

my question is:
I wrote "2016-10-20" as the where clause. When I do it in mysql it shows the results I hope, but when sequelize is executed it changes the value of data clause by "2016-10-19 22:00:00" (two hours before "2016-10-20 00:00:00"!!). Why?

I remeber you that "data" field is a Date field (not a DateTime field)

Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered a new field type when you define the fields of the table in Sequelize. This is the DATAONLY type (instead of DATA type). So, the field definition follows as:

```
        data:
        {
            type:   DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            validate:
            {
                notEmpty: 
                {
                    msg: "-> Falta data"
                }
            }
        },
```

With this file type (DATAONLY) it only considers de date part (not the time part)

Answer (score 4):

Sequelize converts the string you pass in to a Date object, which has a time assigned to it.  If you want to select records on a certain date (rather than at an exact time) you can do so like this:

```
 date: {
     $lt: new Date('2016-10-20'),
     $gt: new Date(new Date('2016-10-20') - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
 }
```

Or in your case:

```
models.TblActivitat.findAll(
            {
                attributes: 
                [
                    'codiAct', 'procedencia', 'pacient', 'proces', 'prova', 'rmn', 'realitzador',
                    [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('data'), '%d-%m-%Y'), 'data']
                ],
                include: models.TblTecnics,
                where: {"data": {
                    $lt: new Date('2016-10-20'),
                    $gt: new Date(new Date('2016-10-20') - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                } },   //dataAAAAMMDD
                order: "registre DESC"
            }).then(function(tblActTec){
                ...
            });
```