# Sequelize - how to compare equality between dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, sequelize.js

How do I compare equality between 2 dates?
Seems like the below does not work:

```
const result: SomeModel= SomeModel.findOne( {where: 
            {
                startTime : {
                    [Op.eq] : someDateTime
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it depends on types of startTime and someDateTime. Add model definoition and a DB type of this column and a value in someDateTime. Also indicate wgat DBMS you are using

Comment: startTime is type Date.
someDateTime is a Date object.

I am using PostgresQL for production. For unit testing SQLite.

Comment: Both sides of an equality comparison contains a time part that's why they are not equal. Try to use something like this: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('date', Sequelize.col('startTime')), Sequelize.fn('date', someDateTime)) (keep in mind that sqlite may not support this function)

Comment: Will this compare the time part of the Date variable too? I want to compare the Date and time both. Both should be equal.

Comment: In this case you should check and compare timezone in a DB and in a variable. Are they equal? What exact type of a column in a PostreSQL DB? With timezone or without it?

Comment: It is "timestamp with time".

I do not understand that Op.gt and Op.lt works perfectly but what is the problem with Op,eq?

Comment: It means that exact date and time with timezone differs from each other. It could be different timezone or just a millisecond difference. Try to convert both dates to UTC and compare them manually

Comment: `[Op.eq]` doesn't work with date. You have to find a way to use `[Op.between]` or `[Op.lt], [Op.gt]` There is somehow a workaround see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926831/sequelize-where-date-clause

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
  const result: SomeModel= SomeModel.findOne( {where: 
                {
                    startTime : {
                        [Op.and] : someDateTime
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is the list of all operations that can be performed

```
Project.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.and]: {a: 5},           // AND (a = 5)
      [Op.or]: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}],  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
      [Op.gt]: 6,                // id > 6
      [Op.gte]: 6,               // id >= 6
      [Op.lt]: 10,               // id < 10
      [Op.lte]: 10,              // id <= 10
      [Op.ne]: 20,               // id != 20
      [Op.between]: [6, 10],     // BETWEEN 6 AND 10
      [Op.notBetween]: [11, 15], // NOT BETWEEN 11 AND 15
      [Op.in]: [1, 2],           // IN [1, 2]
      [Op.notIn]: [1, 2],        // NOT IN [1, 2]
      [Op.like]: '%hat',         // LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.notLike]: '%hat',       // NOT LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.iLike]: '%hat',         // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive)  (PG only)
      [Op.notILike]: '%hat',      // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
      [Op.overlap]: [1, 2],       // && [1, 2] (PG array overlap operator)
      [Op.contains]: [1, 2],      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)
      [Op.contained]: [1, 2],     // <@ [1, 2] (PG array contained by operator)
      [Op.any]: [2,3]            // ANY ARRAY[2, 3]::INTEGER (PG only)
    },
    status: {
      [Op.not]: false           // status NOT FALSE
    }
  }
})
```